# Selecting minimum within JOIN

Tags: mysql, database

I have two tables (listed only fields important for the question):

t_groups

- INT groupId PRIMARY
- VARCHAR(255) grname

t_goods

- INT goodId PRIMARY
- INT groupId
- INT price
- VARCHAR(255) name

Now I need a query, which selects group names and name of the cheapest good in each group. Tried doing it this way:

```
SELECT gr.groupId, grname, g.name
FROM t_groups AS gr
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM t_goods ORDER BY PRICE ASC LIMIT 1) AS g
ON g.groupId = gr.groupId
```

but it doesn't work — returns NULLs in g.name field. It could be easily explained:

SELECT within JOIN statement selects cheapest good first, and then tries to "filter it" by groupId. Obviously, it'll only work for the group cheapest good belongs to.

How do I solve the task?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Why your query does not work

```
SELECT gr.groupId, grname, g.name
FROM t_groups AS gr
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM t_goods ORDER BY PRICE ASC LIMIT 1) AS g
ON g.groupId = gr.groupId
```

The inner query selects *the absolutely cheapest good* (irrespective of group) in your database. Therefore, when you `LEFT JOIN` the groups to this result set, only the group which actually includes the universally cheapest good has a matching row (that group should get the `g.name` column filled properly). However, due to the way `LEFT JOIN` works all other groups will get `NULL` as the value of all columns in `g`.

### The correct solution

First, you need to select the cheapest price in each group. This is easy:

```
SELECT groupId, MIN(price) AS minPrice FROM t_goods GROUP BY (groupId)
```

However the cheapest price is not useful without the associated `goodId`. The problem is that it's not meaningful to write something like:

```
/* does not make sense, although MySql has historically allowed it */
SELECT goodId, groupId, MIN(price) AS minPrice FROM t_goods GROUP BY (groupId)
```

The reason is that you cannot select a non-grouped column (i.e. `goodId`) unless you wrap it in an aggregate function (such as `MIN`): we don't know *which* `goodId` you want from among those that share the same `groupId`.

The correct, portable way to get the `goodId` of the cheapest goods in each group is

```
SELECT goodId, temp.groupId, temp.minPrice
FROM (SELECT groupId, MIN(price) AS minPrice FROM t_goods GROUP BY groupId) temp
      JOIN t_goods ON temp.groupId = t_goods.groupId AND temp.minPrice = t_goods.price)
```

The above query first finds out the cheapest price per group, and then joins to the goods table again to find the `goodId`s of the goods having that price inside that group.

**Important:** if multiple goods have an equal cheapest price in a group, this query will return *all* of them. If you only want *one* result per group you have to specify the tiebreaker, for example:

```
SELECT MIN(goodId), temp.groupId, MIN(temp.minPrice)
FROM (SELECT groupId, MIN(price) AS minPrice FROM t_goods GROUP BY groupId) temp
      JOIN t_goods ON temp.groupId = t_goods.groupId AND temp.minPrice = t_goods.price)
GROUP BY temp.groupId
```

With this query in hand, you can then find the name and price of the single cheapest good in each group (lowest `goodId` will be used as tiebreaker):

```
SELECT groupId, grname, gd.name, t3.minPrice
FROM t_groups AS gr
LEFT JOIN (SELECT MIN(goodId) AS goodId, t1.groupId, MIN(t1.minPrice) AS minPrice
           FROM (SELECT groupId, MIN(price) AS minPrice FROM t_goods GROUP BY groupId) t1
                 JOIN t_goods ON t1.groupId = t_goods.groupId AND t1.minPrice = t_goods.price
           ) t2
) t3 ON gr.groupId = t3.groupId
LEFT JOIN t_goods gd ON t3.goodId = gd.goodId
```

This final query performs two joins at its "outer" level:

- joins groups with the "`goodId` and cheapest price for each group" table to get the `goodId` and cheapest price
- then joins with the goods table to get the name of the good with this `goodId`

It will produce only one good per group, even if multiple goods are tied for cheapest.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you could do it:

```
select 
  t_groups.grname as `name of group`,
  t_goods.name as `name of good`
from (
  select 
    groupId, 
    min(price) as min_price
  from t_goods 
  group by groupId
) as mins
inner join t_goods
  on mins.groupId = t_goods.groupId and mins.min_price = t_goods.price
inner join t_groups
  on mins.groupId = t_groups.groupId
```

How this works:

- `mins` subquery gets the minimum price for each groupId
- joining `mins` to `t_goods` pulls all of the goods out that have the minimum price in their group.  Note that this could return multiple goods in a single group, if there are multiple goods with the minimum price
- that's then joined to `t_groups` to get the group name

---

Your query was presumably returning NULLs because it was `left join`ing to a subquery with only one row.

Comment: It should be noted that this will produce multiple rows per group inside which multiple goods are tied for cheapest.